# Django Rest Framework has_object_permission not returning specified "message"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created a permission class for Detail View in DRF as below

```
class IsDealOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "You are Not Authorized to Access the Deal"
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        user_roles = view.request.STR_USER_ROLES
        user_id = view.request.STR_USER_ID
        company_id = view.request.STR_COMPANY_ID

        if settings.CRM_ROLE in user_roles:
            return True

        if obj.investor_id == user_id:
            return True

        if obj.distributor_id:
            if obj.distributor_id == user_id:
                return True

        if obj.partner_id:
            if (obj.partner_id == company_id) and (settings.PARTNER_ROLE in user_roles):
                return True

        return False
```

But when the object level permission is not specified, I am getting the error "Authentication Credentials were not provided". Why is it not returning the message specified in message attribute (As per DRF docs)?

Answer (score 0):

In the django rest framework, Authentication and Authorization are handled separately where Authentication is handled first (are you an authenticated user) and THEN Authorization (does your user have the permissions required to do this thing). It looks like you're getting tripped up on Authentication and it's never getting to your Authorization class at all.

If you want to skip over the Authentication check, you can set `authentication_classes = []` in your viewset. This *should* then check Authorization and return your proper message.

Comment: Sure, but what I'm saying is perhaps your authentication class isn't set up properly. Regardless of it being an authenticated request, the Authentication class is throwing the error & it never even gets to the Authorization class. Simply being an authenticated request means nothing if you've not set up your Authentication class properly to recognize the authentication as valid. Are you using token authentication? Session authentication? Are you requesting from a browser? Postman? It matters in setting up your Authentication class properly. THEN you can deal with your Authorization class.

Comment: I am using this permission class for View written in one of the services in the application i am working on. For this service i am handling auth my calling authentication service in a Custom Middleware and it is getting successfully authenticated there.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I am saying. I'm not arguing that your request is authenticated. I am sure it is. The problem is that the Django Rest Framework Authentication class you are using is tripping up. Your code is never even MAKING it to your Authorization class bc the Authentication class does not recognize your authenticated request as valid. This can be for several reasons. To tell you more I need to know the default drf authentication class you're using. It's probably set in settings.py.